# Mongoose - How to find a Document inside an array of Documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that has an array of documents, I want to be able to find an specific document inside this array without knowing the _id of the main document:

```
const organizationSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  members: {
   type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Member" }],
   default: [],
  }
 });
```

Members looks like this:

```
const memberSchema = new Schema({
 user: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "User",
  required: true,
 },
 status: { type: String, enum: Status, required: true },
});
```

Like I said before, I would like to find an Organization using the ID of an User inside the Members document, I tried to do an aggregate, but I'm doing something wrong as it just returns an empty array:

```
const existingOrganization = await Organization.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "members.user._id": objectId },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$members",
  },
]);
```

Is it possible to do the search in the first place?

Edit:

Here's how the document should look when retrieved from the database:

```
[
{
    "_id": "63376128758f036eafa9277f",
    "name": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": "63376128758f036eafa9277e",
            "user": {
                "_id": "63067438faa89240f4371f6e",
                "email": "test2@test.com",
            },
            "status": "Accepted",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

Comment: The search is absolutely possible, as demonstrated in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/naDOq16o3l9).  So the main question is just what the document in the database actually looks like.  Can you post the sample document directly instead of the Mongoose schema for it?

Comment: @user20042973 I edited the post with the document. I tried the find from the playground but it returns an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the document!  Can you be more specific about what you did in the playground that didn't work? Sharing a link would be great. [Here is my attempt](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8gR5TrFULMN) given your sample document that seems to work fine.

Comment: @user20042973 I tried to do the same in the playground and it actually worked, but when I tried the same in my project it just returns an empty array for some reason, I'm doing `organization.find({ "members.user._id": userId })` right now but it doesn't work

Comment: Right. So the things to check are 1) that the app is connecting to the right place and namespace (db name and collection name), 2) that the structure of the document in the database is as you expect (.find({}), and 3) that userId is resolving to a value that matches what is in the database. Be sure to check the _type_ of the value as well (eg is it a string or an ObjectId that is stored?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by using aggregate pipelines for `Member` collection.

1. Filter `members` in `$match` stage
2. `$lookup` for `organizations` which includes filtered `members`
3. `$group` all the organizations
4. `$replaceRoot` with `organization` to return a list of `organizations`
5. populate members

The solution could be:

```js
  const existingOrganization = await Member.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        user: objectId
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "organizations",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "members",
        as: "organizations"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$organizations"
      }
    },
    { $group: { _id: "$organizations._id", data: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data.organizations" } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "members",
        localField: "members",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "members"
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I never really used aggregate before so I didn't know you could replace the root, that's actually really useful

Comment: Ali, this works but I just noticed that the "members" array is not populated with the values of the documents, but with the _ids, is there a solution for this?

Comment: @LuisDanielCova I have updated the answer so that the `members` array is now populated